# How to enable ajax validations in contact form 7

Tags: wordpress

How can i enable ajax validations in contact form 7.
Defaultly the page is reloading after submission,
Need to display errors without page reload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Default , CF7 come with ajax validation.
May be there are some conflict between the plugins that you have installed.
Please check the console and based on that please google or paste the console error here

Answer (score 0):

I just removed my javascript link in my file.

Now it is working fine